# Upload file to Vsphere datastore with go fails datastore not found

Tags: go, file-upload, datastore, vsphere

I have problems uploading an iso file to a datastore. The server (vcsim)  says:

`2018/05/17 11:55:54 failed to locate datastore with query params: dcPath=%2FDC0&dsName=LocalDS_0`

The information about the datastore is:

`govc datastore.upload -dc="DC0" -k=true -ds LocalDS_0 -debug=true /home/jorge/Downloads/ipxe.iso ipxe.iso
[17-05-18 13:54:33] Uploading... Error: 404 Not Found
govc: 404 Not Found`

But when I execute this command it fails:

`govc datastore.info -dc="DC0" -k=true LocalDS_0
Name:        LocalDS_0
  Path:      /DC0/datastore/LocalDS_0
  Type:      local
  URL:       /tmp/govcsim-DC0-LocalDS_0-926708808
  Capacity:  0.9 GB
  Free:      0.5 GB`

What am I doing wrong? What are the steps to create a datastore and upload a file to it?

Comment: It was a bug in the vcim code. I have solved it through a PR.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the PR please?

Comment: I was already merged in the main repository: https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/pull/1131

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar error, but it turns out the application returning the error wanted a full path to the object instead of a short name like `LocalDS_0`.